# Play one of more wav files while key is pressed

Tags: c#

I need to play a sound or sounds while a key is pressed, when the key or keys are no longer pressed the sound stops immediately.

I am currently using BASS.net sound library and the sound is called like this:

```
        public class Foo
        {
            public static int GetStream1(string path)
            {
                return Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(path, 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT | BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN);
            }
            public static int GetStream2(string path)
            {
                return Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(path, 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT | BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN);
            }
        }

        private void setupPlayer()
        {
            stream1 = Foo.GetStream1(path1.Text);
            stream2 = Foo.GetStream2(path2.Text);
        }

//when the key1 is down/something to handle when the key is down
                Bass.BASS_Init(1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, this.Handle);
                Bass.BASS_SetDevice(1);
                Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(Foo.GetStream1(path1.Text), false);

//when the key1 is up/something to handle when the key is up
                Bass.BASS_StreamFree(Foo.GetStream1(path1.Text));
                Bass.BASS_SetDevice(1);
                Bass.BASS_Free();

//when the key2 is down/something to handle when the key is down
                Bass.BASS_Init(2, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, this.Handle);
                Bass.BASS_SetDevice(2);
                Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(Foo.GetStream1(path2.Text), false);

//when the key2 is up/something to handle when the key is up
                Bass.BASS_StreamFree(Foo.GetStream2(path2.Text));
                Bass.BASS_SetDevice(2);
                Bass.BASS_Free();
```

As I said when the key is down play the sound, when the key is up the sound stops. In adition, you can press more than 1 key and the files will play independently of the other key pressed or released, in other terms, pressing and releasing a key should not affect the other keys being pressed or released at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're aiming for, but .NET framework allows for Control (Window component) events. And one of those events is [OnKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Inside that method, you're given a view of the KeyEventArgs e parameter. That parameter can tell you which key is being pressed via `e.KeyCode` and then you can compare that key against your preset keys to determine which music to play. With that being said, holding down multiple keys at different times will fire off another instance of this event which solves your second request.

Good luck & have fun!